# Dask workers run out of memory just before finishing when writing parquet files

Tags: python, parquet, dask

I am trying to convert a number of large .csv files to the parquet format using python and dask.

This is the code that I use:

```
trans = dd.read_csv(os.path.join(TRANS_PATH, "*.TXT"), 
                        sep=";", dtype=col_types, parse_dates=['salesdate'])

trans = trans.drop('salestime', axis=1)
trans['month_year'] = trans['salesdate'].dt.strftime('M_%Y_%m')

trans['chainid'] = '41'
trans['key'] = trans['chainid'] + trans['barcode']
trans = trans.join(attribs[['catcode']], on=['key'])

start = default_timer()
trans.to_parquet(PARQUET_PATH, engine="fastparquet", compression='snappy',
                     partition_on=['catcode', 'month_year'], append=False)
end = default_timer()
print("Done in {} secs.".format(end - start) )
```

The code seems to run fine and all the parquet files are created under the correct directories with no warnings almost until the end. The graph execution reaches until here:
[image]

At this point the program gets stuck for a minute or so, and then the following warnings get raised:

```
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget.  Restarting
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker process 16996 was killed by signal 15
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
```

After the warning, a few hundred processes get restarted and are executed again:
[image]

This happens three times and the program finally crashes:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KilledWorker                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-f644e4fa53ea> in <module>()
     27 start = default_timer()
     28 trans.to_parquet(PARQUET_PATH, engine="fastparquet", compression='snappy',
---> 29                      partition_on=['catcode', 'month_year'], append=False)
```

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

Comment: Same problem, any help?